# Twitter connection failed - 500 internal error received

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter, oauth

I'm using php framework CodeIgniter for Twitter connection on website. The problem is, that after connecting to Twitter and redirecting to callback URL I'm always seeing this 500 error.

[image: error]

this is my code:

```
public function callback()
{
    if ( $this->input->get('oauth_token') && ($this->session->userdata('twitter_request_token') !== $this->input->get('oauth_token')) ) {
        $this->reset_session();
        echo 'reset session';
        //redirect(base_url('/twitter/auth'));
    } else {
        $access_token = $this->connection->getAccessToken($this->input->get('oauth_verifier'));
        /*echo '<pre>';
        print_r($this->connection);
        echo '</pre>';*/

        if ( $this->connection->http_code == 200 ) {
            $this->session->set_userdata('twitter_access_token', $access_token['oauth_token']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('twitter_access_token_secret', $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('twitter_user_id', $access_token['user_id']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('twitter_screen_name', $access_token['screen_name']);

            $this->session->unset_userdata('twitter_request_token');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('twitter_request_token_secret');

            echo 'http code 200 - all is fine, user connected';
            //redirect(base_url('/'));
        } else {
            echo 'http code not 200 - not all is fine, user not connected';
            // An error occured. Add your notification code here.
            //redirect(base_url('/'));
        }
    }
}
```

and at this moment I don't even know why this error is spawning to me... If i reload page on this error, then I see other error:

[image: error 2]

Comment: Print out `$access_token` before use and see it's structure.

Comment: After printing `$access_token` it gives me this http://prntscr.com/7ickgz but if I try check connection http code or smth - it gives me 500 error..

Comment: Can you link library you use for this? Sidenote: string argument in `base_url()` function shouldn't start with slash because base_url() already is finishing with slash if well set in `APPPATH . 'config/config.php'` file.

Comment: @Tpojka I'm using this library https://github.com/MunGell/Codeigniter-TwitterOAuth

Comment: You commented some parts of code out. What is going on when you use code as is, as provded (i.e. example controller)?